# How To Export Large CSV File From SAS Viya

Tags: csv, sql, export, sas

I have a large CSV file of about 7 million observations that i want to export from SAS Viya. The problem is that SAS viya doesn't allow me to do so because it is too large. So I had to divide it into "Mini" datasets of 100,000 observations each.

Does anyone know how I can export it in full without dividing?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How To export all the file without dividing it.

Comment: You may want to contact SAS Viya customer support for that because it seems a limitation of the software. Trying to circumvent it it's not allowed either.

Comment: That's what i'll do i think , thank you